# How can I use boolean on datatype: html?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core

How can I use an `boolean` when my `dataType` is `html`? When my `controller` detects that there's no data on my `sql`, it should throw as `false` in my `controller` which is working, I just need to throw the `boolean` on my `ajax` as `false`. Im aware that using an `html` is automatically as `true` which is if I use an `operator`. It return as `true`. But how can I make it as `false` too?

Here's my controller:

```
if (Reader.HasRows == true)
   {
       return View("TrueViewPort");
   } else
   {
      return View("FalseViewPort");
   }
```

Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "UrlToController",
    type: "GET",
    data: {
        uname: uname
    },
    dataType: "html",
    success: (function (result) {
        if (result == true) { //even if its false, it always throw here
        $('#wishlist-carousel').html(result); //if data detected carousel should be called
            //Something elements when the data is true
        } else {
           //Something elements when the data is false
        $(".no-page").html(result); //if no data. no carousel should detect
        }
    }),
    error: (function (xhr, status) {
        alert(status);
    })
})
```

EDIT:

These should appear on my `TrueViewPort`:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    @for (int i = 0, x = 1; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++, x++)
    {
        <div class="item">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img-top">
                        <img src="~/images/link/@Model.Rows[i][0]" />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @Model.Rows[i][1]
                        <br />
                        @Model.Rows[i][2]
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
else //When the server detected that there's no data, it should throw the else statement which is working
{
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="not-found-404">
                404
            </div>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="not-found">
                ITEMS NOT FOUND
            </div>
                <br />
            <div class="not-found-title">
                Don't you have any want on the shop?
            </div>
                <br />
            <div class="not-found-content">
                Looks like you still haven't putting anything on your wishlist do you?
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And here's what appear on my screen when launching it.
Using both `if else operators to ==`
[image: First result]

Using `if as == true` and `else`
[image: Second Result]

My `.cshtml`:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="true">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="wishlist-carousel"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="no-page"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add a `console.log( result)`  to show what it is for real

Comment: Its a log for `else` element, but when I use `result == true` even the data is `true` it will throw on `else` as well.

Comment: Add `console.log(result)` and add the results to your question.

Comment: you are making an ajax call to your controller action and returning a view!! you should return a JSON result, instead of `return View("TrueViewPort");` use `return JsonResult(true)`

Comment: Is it still going to call my another `.cshtml` which is my `TrueViewPort`?

Comment: I added some informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your `TrueViewPort` as `if else statement` as you can see you given your `TrueViewpor` with 2 different `<div>`

Lets assume that you have any `events` on your `javascript`

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
       success: function(result) {
          $(".no-page").html(result); //if no data. no carousel should detect
          $('#wishlist-carousel').html(result); 
          //Put here your owl function
       }
    })
  })
```

Then change your `.cshtml` to:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="true">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="wishlist-carousel"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="no-page"></div> //separate these one, so if there's no data, the result will go here.
```

Then on your `TrueViewPort`:

```
@if (Model != null && Model.Rows.Count != 0)
{
    @for (int i = 0, x = 1; i < Model.Rows.Count; i++, x++)
    {
        //add a <style> here to hide the no-page.
    }
}
else 
    {
       //add a <style> here to hide the owl carousel
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code given, but it gives me a blank `owl-item` which is the `<style>` do you have any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: There are few tricks that can be used, you can base it on here [Owl Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27947789/how-to-re-render-a-owl-carousel-item)

Answer (score 0):

You could just return one view and make the judement with the count of the target data in your target div

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()  {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:44332/Home/Partial",
            success: function (result) {                
                var a = $("#test").children().length;
                console.log(a);
                if (a == 0) {
                    $(".no-page").html(result);
                }
                else {
                    $("#wishlist-carousel").html(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
</script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
        <div class="true">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="wishlist-carousel">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="no-page"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="test">
    <a>test</a>
</div>
```

Result1：
There's a "test" text in `<div id="test"></div>`
[image]
Delete the text:
[image]